# Intellij unitest Exception encountered when invoking run on a nested suite - java.net.BindException: Permission denied

Tags: scala, jetty

I am new to scalatest and when I finished the project I add a test file.
Is there any place that I should particularly pay attention to?
I met this problem when I want to run a unitest in intelli idea

```
    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:50594,suspend=y,server=n -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Users/xuyin/Library/Application Support/IdeaIC13/Scala/lib/scala-plugin-runners.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-doclet.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/htmlconverter.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/JObjC.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Users/xuyin/codebase/api-server/target/scala-2.10/test-classes:/Users/xuyin/codebase/api-server/target/scala-2.10/classes:/Users/xuyin/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.1/lib/scala-library.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.slick/slick_2.10/jars/slick_2.10-1.0.0.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/jars/slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-nop/jars/slf4j-nop-1.6.4.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/com.h2database/h2/jars/h2-1.3.166.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/mysql/mysql-connector-java/jars/mysql-connector-java-5.1.13.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/org.scalaquery/scalaquery_2.9.1-1/jars/scalaquery_2.9.1-1-0.10.0-M1.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter/finagle-core_2.10/jars/finagle-core_2.10-6.2.0.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty/bundles/netty-3.5.5.Final.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter/util-core_2.10/jars/util-core_2.10-6.2.0.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter/util-collection_2.10/jars/util-collection_2.10-6.2.0.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/com.google.guava/guava/jars/guava-13.0.1.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/com.google.guava/guava/jars/guava-11.0.2.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/commons-collections/commons-collections/jars/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter/util-hashing_2.10/jars/util-hashing_2.10-6.2.0.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter/util-jvm_2.10/jars/util-jvm_2.10-6.2.0.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter/util-logging_2.10/jars/util-logging_2.10-6.2.0.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter/util-app_2.10/jars/util-app_2.10-6.2.0.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter/finagle-http_2.10/jars/finagle-http_2.10-6.2.0.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter/util-codec_2.10/jars/util-codec_2.10-6.2.0.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/commons-codec/commons-codec/jars/commons-codec-1.6.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/commons-codec/commons-codec/jars/commons-codec-1.5.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/commons-lang/commons-lang/jars/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter/finagle-ostrich4_2.10/jars/finagle-ostrich4_2.10-6.2.0.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter/ostrich_2.10/jars/ostrich_2.10-9.1.0.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter/util-eval_2.10/jars/util-eval_2.10-6.1.0.jar:/Users/xuyin/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.1/lib/scala-compiler.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect/jars/scala-reflect-2.10.1.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter/scala-json_2.10/jars/scala-json_2.10-3.0.1.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/net.liftweb/lift-json_2.10/jars/lift-json_2.10-2.5.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scalap/jars/scalap-2.10.0.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/com.thoughtworks.paranamer/paranamer/jars/paranamer-2.4.1.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/log4j/log4j/bundles/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/log4j/log4j/jars/log4j-1.2.14.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/com.github.sgroschupf/zkclient/jars/zkclient-0.1.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.zookeeper/zookeeper/jars/zookeeper-3.3.3.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/jline/jline/jars/jline-0.9.94.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/junit/junit/jars/junit-3.8.1.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/org.scalatest/scalatest_2.10/jars/scalatest_2.10-1.9.1.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-actors/jars/scala-actors-2.10.0.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/com.github.tomakehurst/wiremock/jars/wiremock-1.33.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/net.sf.jopt-simple/jopt-simple/jars/jopt-simple-4.3.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/jars/jackson-core-2.1.2.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/org.mortbay.jetty/jetty/jars/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/org.mortbay.jetty/jetty-util/jars/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/org.mortbay.jetty/servlet-api/jars/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path/bundles/json-path-0.8.1.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/net.minidev/json-smart/jars/json-smart-1.1.1.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/jars/httpclient-4.2.3.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/jars/httpcore-4.2.2.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/commons-logging/commons-logging/jars/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/jars/jackson-annotations-2.1.2.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/junit/junit-dep/jars/junit-dep-4.10.jar:/Users/xuyin/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/jars/jackson-databind-2.1.2.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 13 CE.app/lib/idea_rt.jar" org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner -s com.umeng.push.apiserver.ApiServerServiceSpec -showProgressMessages true -C org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestReporter
Testing started at PM12:49 ...
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:50594', transport: 'socket'

Exception encountered when invoking run on a nested suite - java.net.BindException: Permission denied
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Permission denied
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WireMockServer.start(WireMockServer.java:168)
    at com.umeng.push.apiserver.ApiServerServiceSpec.beforeAll(ApiServerServiceSpec.scala:33)
    at org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll$class.beforeAll(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:150)
    at com.umeng.push.apiserver.ApiServerServiceSpec.beforeAll(ApiServerServiceSpec.scala:26)
    at org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll$class.run(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:211)
    at com.umeng.push.apiserver.ApiServerServiceSpec.run(ApiServerServiceSpec.scala:26)
    at org.scalatest.tools.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.scala:60)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$3.apply(Runner.scala:1604)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$3.apply(Runner.scala:1601)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun(Runner.scala:1601)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$2.apply(Runner.scala:705)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$2.apply(Runner.scala:704)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.withClassLoaderAndDispatchReporter(Runner.scala:1645)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:703)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.run(Runner.scala:592)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner.run(Runner.scala)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.runScalaTest1(ScalaTestRunner.java:213)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.main(ScalaTestRunner.java:37)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Permission denied
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.newServerSocket(SocketConnector.java:80)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.open(SocketConnector.java:73)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:283)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.doStart(SocketConnector.java:147)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:235)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WireMockServer.start(WireMockServer.java:166)
    ... 18 more
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:50594', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jetty is probably trying to open a restricted port (like 80), and you are not running as root. Check the port number your test code is telling it to use (or it might be using a default).

Comment: Indeed! The test case was trying to open a 80 port, and after I changed to localhost, it worked.

Comment: Is there any way to make it work when I really want to try open a 80 port?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I was using a USB surf stick for connecting to the internet, with some provider specific software to operate the surf stick. When disconnecting the stick (and thereby disconnecting from the internet), debugging worked fine for me. The stick software somehow messed up the routing of my computer, such that it tried to connect to `localhost` via the stick, which failed because the port number was blocked.

So, check if you have a similar configuration, and if it works when you turn off your internet connection.

Alternatively, this might also be a firewall issue. Try turning off your firewall for a while.

I strongly recommend disconnecting from the internet while your firewall is turned off!